# Is there an equivalent to Python response.history in C# (.NET 6)?

Tags: python, c#, .net, httprequest

I need to get one response before the final one made in C# and its header.

I can do it in python using:

```
response = requests.post(f"{uri}")

response.history #List
```

In C# I'm currently usign HttpClient to make the POST request, but I can only get the final response with
`var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`
and
`var responseHeader = response.Headers;`

Comment: You're getting one response object per request, why not just, read/save the one you're interested in when it is returned?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not making N requests, just one. My current request auto make another 2 requests.  
**uri ---auto-request--> uri2 ---auto-request--> uri3** . 

With C# making the request to uri, I get the response from uri3, but I need the uri2 content

Comment: You will likely have to disable automatic redirect and follow redirection chain manually, I believe HttpClient doesn't provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable automatic redirection in HttpClient like this:

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false};
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

// Use httpClient. It will not automatically redirect
```

So you have to manually check the status code in Response and redirect if necessary but can keep track of redirects this way.